# Record create in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-id, visual-flows

I am simply creating a record from visual flows. Below is the snapshot of the record create page.
[image: Record create page]

On execution of the flow I receive an exception in my mailbox saying 
 **INVALID_ID_FIELD: Record ID: id value of incorrect type:** 
Thanks in advance.
P.S- There is no mandatory field in the flow.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Record Create]

Create a variable Input and Output type

[image: variable]

It will create a record.